# IBM ODM - Exit criteria

Tags: ibm-odm

How does IBM ODM rule exit criteria work?

For example: For credit card approval, I have 5 rules for Platinum, Gold, Silver, Bronze, Flex.

If person's credit history matches Platinum can approve, he is also eligible for all remaining cards by default: all the 5 rules will execute. But I need to exit after first rule fires, because the person approved for Platinum, he is also eligible for other cards (but not required).

Answer (score 0):

maybe create an additional condition in your rules like :

```
if customer has platinum and is not approved 
then
- approve customer 
- do something else
...
```

hope this helps
best
Emmanuel

```
if customer has gold and is not approved 
then
- approve customer 
- do something else
...
```